Multiprocessing for combining F3D viewer and tkinter in Python?
I've been wondering how I could approach combining F3D viewer and tkinter gui.
The required smallest amount of code is as followed. Unfortunately engine.interactor and tkinter mainloop are two different loops so they can't be handled at the same time. Would multiprocessing be better choice in this case instead of threading?
import tkinter as tk

import f3d

engine = f3d.Engine(f3d.Window.NATIVE)
frame = tk.Tk()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine.window.render()
    engine.interactor.start()
    
    frame.mainloop()

The idea is to have two windows open and while other is inactive, it would be put to sleep while the other is active.

dont hesitate to come to our discord to discuss this :)
https://discord.f3d.app
